# Add printout date and time when creating a PDF document

Tags: pdf, scripting, pdf-generation

I am using PDFCreator from pdfforge to create .pdf documents. There are some work instructions or reports where it is significant to state when the document was printed. I though this should be possible to add such an information on each page of a pdf document when it is printed, similarly to most of normal printers. I failed to find such an option in PDFCreator.

I actually found something similar, which is called 'Stamp text' under Document section in Profile settings. This however adds the field I want, but places it in the middle of the page.

Most probably this should be possible to achieve this with scripts, but I have no experience in writing such. Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: The content of a pdf is mostly finalised when it is created, no change will happen at printing time.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the postscrpt file before the PDFCreator uses it to create PDF? Maybe this is the solution?